# Store returned objects into array javascript Microsoft Azure

Tags: javascript, azure-mobile-services

I have a sql statement

```
var sql = "SELECT lastName FROM Class";
```

How can I store the results in array in Microsoft Azure scripts?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mssql object from your server-side script. Specifically, call `mssql.query(sql, params, options)`:

```
mssql.query('SELECT lastName FROM Class', {
   success: function(results) {
      // results will be your array
   },
   error: function(err) {
      // do something with an error
   }
});
```

You can find details and examples on this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj554212.aspx